# Help with duplicating rows based on a field using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have the following data set with the 3rd field consists of 0's and 1's

```
Input 

1 2 1
2 4 0
3 3 1
4 1 1
5 0 0
```

I wish to expand the data set to the following format

1. Duplicate each row based on the 2nd field and
2. Replace only the "new" 1's (obtain after duplication) in the 3rd field by 0

How can I do this with AWK?

Thanks

```
Output 
1 2 1
1 2 0
2 4 0
2 4 0
2 4 0
2 4 0
3 3 1
3 3 0
3 3 0
4 1 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print; $3=0; for (i=1; i<$2; i++) print}' inputfile
```

If you want to actually skip records with a zero in the second field (as your example seems to show):

```
awk '{if ($2>0) print; $3=0; for (i=1; i<$2; i++) print}' inputfile
```

Comment: Dennis. it works fine. I don't quite understand the order of statement $3=0 before duplicating takes place. BTW, How can I give feedback on all the help I have been receiving from stackoverflow?

Comment: @Tony: First, the record is printed, then the third field is changed to 0, then the record is printed as many times as the value in the second field (minus 1, because it's "less than" `<` instead of "less than or equal" `<=`). So the record is always printed once (unless you're using the skip-zero version). The `for` loop only executes if `$2` is *greater than* 1 so if it's 0 or 1 there's no duplicate. Regarding feedback, there are several things that you can do (even doing all of them). First, accepting and upvoting answers.

Comment: @Tony: (cont) Second, asking and answering questions (this actually does provide feedback, in more ways than one). Tell your friends, family and coworkers about SO and the other Stack Exchange sites (I see you're not yet a member of any of the others). Make blog posts, tweets and other social media mentions. Use the `link` link found under each question when you link to specific ones - it contains your user number. Participate in the Meta sites and Chat. Participate in Area 51. Finally, you could send email to the Contact Us address at the bottom of the page.